# Why is having high p-value makes dependent variable significant in backward elimination?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

In backward elimination, I heard the steps of **fitting the model by keep removing the highest p-value(a.k.a. insignificant independent variable) each time** like below

> 1. Select a significance level to stay in the model(e.g. SL = 0.05)
> 2. Fit the full model with all possible predictors
> 3. Consider the predictor with the **highest P-Value(P > SL)**
> 4. Remove the predictor
> 5. Fit model without this variable **(Repeat step 3-5 until P <= SL)**

But the part which I don't get is **why is having higher p-value makes the corresponding independent variable insignificant**. Doesn't having **high p-value** mean it's more close to the null hypothesis so that that variable is more significant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the Null Hypothesis is that the predictor is not significant. Taken from the book Introduction to Statistical Learning:

- Null Hypothesis: There is no relationship between X and Y
- Alternative Hypothesis: There is some relationship between X and Y

If we have a high p-value, we have an expressive result showing that the null hypothesis is correct and therefore the estimated coefficient come from a normal distribution around zero and can be discarded. I hope this answer your question, please let any comment if you need more help.

Comment: Also, as an extra comment: I think you should also calculate other metrics as well and not only p-values, such as MSE/MAE, R_squared, BIC, etc. This is because that when variables are interacting some can have high/low p-values due chance, if you have a significant amount of predictors. I highly recommend that you read chapters 3 and 6 from ISLR book, the authors offer a free pdf version on their website:  http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! but I am a bit confused about the Null Hypothesis because Wikipedia defines it as what you've said, but whenever I search examples of the Null Hypothesis and Alternative Hypothesis, it gives me simple examples like this link(in this case pizza delivery time example)  : https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/what-a-p-value-tells-you-about-statistical-data/ and I don't get how I can relate this to the definition of the Null Hypothesis which is "There is no relationship between X and Y"

Comment: In this pizza example we have a Null Hypothesis that states the average delivery time is 30 minutes or less, that is, you will sample some deliveries, calculate the mean and test your results to see if this *calculated_mean* comes from a distribution which the mean is 30 minutes. Then you get a result of 0.001, strongly indicating that we have a low probability of seeing a value calculated_mean coming from a distribution where the original mean is 30 minutes and we then reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: The part you are getting confused is here:
- "Doesn't having high p-value mean it's more close to the null hypothesis so that that variable is more significant?"
The Null Hypothesis on regression case is that the variable is not significant, that is, zero. And not that the variable is significant. Can you see this?
Please, if you have any question don't hesitate to keep commenting, let's clarify that. :)

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much for this detailed explanation! To sum up, can I think the null hypothesis on regression as "The variable has no relationship between the mean and itself" and if the p-value is high, it means hypothesis is likely true which means the variable is meaningless? Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Oh and in the link I added, I still am confused about how I can relate the definition of null hypothesis which is "There is no relationship between X and Y" to the null hypothesis they have set up in the link which is "the average delivery time is 30 minutes or less".

Comment: No, in regression your Null Hypothesis is that the coefficients are zero, not the mean. Null hypothesis is not something fixed, you can define anything to test against. In the pizza case, it could be other way around, that is, the Null Hypothesis could be that the average delivery time is more than 30 minutes. Don't mix both tests, in the regression case you are testing to check if your coefficient is zero, then a high p-value indicates that this is true. In the pizza case you want to check if the average is 30 minutes, then a high p-value indicates that is true (But of course, we had a low p)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! Thanks to you, I think I got to grasp the concept :D